# Is there a way to display an error message if the table is not updated?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to update a row in a table:

```
try
{
    string sql ="UPDATE TableNAme SET FirstName ='John' WHERE ID = 123";

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    connection.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Based on the ID (key), it works perfectly if the ID was in the table, but if the ID doesn't exist in the table it shows no error message.

Is there a way that I can know if the ID was not found?

Comment: yes, check the contents of the exception

Comment: Check your exception, dont ignore exception.

Comment: @BugFinder if the `ID` is not found, there is no exception.

Comment: You can get the number of rows affected from the return of the ExecuteNonQuery() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected. You can make use of that:

```
int affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (affectedRows == 0)
{
    // show error;
}
else
{
    // success;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you connect to (Microsoft) **SQL Server**, you need to use **`SqlConnection`** and **`SqlCommand`** - not `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`.

Secondly - the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call returns an `int` which defines the number of rows affected - read that out and if it's 0, then no update was made.

```
int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (rowsAffected == 0)
{
    // show message - no rows updated
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `SET NOCOUNT` is `ON`, the count is not returned. When `SET NOCOUNT` is `OFF`, the count is returned.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

Other way is to use pure SQL or check your server default settings `SET NOCOUNT { ON | OFF }` :

```
// Will return always 0  if SET NOCOUNT is ON.!!!
int affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`@@ROWCOUNT` (Transact-SQL)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187316.aspx

If the number of rows is more than 2 billion, use ROWCOUNT_BIG https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms181406.aspx

!!!! The @@ROWCOUNT function is updated even when SET NOCOUNT is ON.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

I personalty will do SQL

```
      USE AdventureWorks2012;  
      GO  

      UPDATE HumanResources.Employee   
      SET JobTitle = N'Executive'  
      WHERE NationalIDNumber = 123456789  

      IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0  
      PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated';  
      GO
```

Other argument to use SQL is if you move this code to a stored procedure.

Return value will be wrong if  SET NOCOUNT is ON.

I think -1 or 0